# How to get the last 2 digits number using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am entering the digits in the text field as `1528799`, can any one tell me how to get last 2 digits of the given number using jquery or javascript

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just modulo it with 100

```
parseInt(document.getElementById("inputField").value, 10) % 100
```

For example

```
console.log(1528799 % 100);
```

will print `99`

Comment: This won't work if you have `1528709`. The result in this case will be `9` though you may be want to have `09`